# Field parent has incomplete type

Tags: c

I'm new to C, and can't get this program to compile. Here's the relevant portion of code:

```
typedef struct {
    git_odb_backend parent;

    redisContext *db;
} hiredis_backend;
```

Compiling results in an error:

```
error: field 'parent' has incomplete type
```

Here's the complete file: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2-backends/blob/master/redis/hiredis.c

Other answers to similar questions mention a header file. Should there be a hiredis.h file as well?

**EDIT** `git_odb_backend` is defined here: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/include/git2/sys/odb_backend.h

Comment: What is the definition of `git_odb_backend`?  If it's not `typedef`ed, keyword `struct` may need to be prepended to `git_odb_backend parent;`.

Comment: Just edited the question to add that.

Comment: Actually, just realized that the library I'm compiling is based on an outdated version of libgit2. Submitting a pull request with the update.

Comment: For future searches: https://github.com/nathancahill/libgit2-backends/commit/df1d6f65d8153b4da558c620bab74bb060d1063c

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about what `git_odb_backend` is (and neither does the compiler) so here's my advice.

The file `hiredis.c` needs to know the full declaration of `git_odb_backend` to allow you to declare it as a non-pointer member variable. This is because the compiler needs to know things about the `git_odb_backend` such as: What is its size? How do I construct it? It doesn't need to know the function implementations, just what the struct looks like.

So you need to find the header file that declares `git_odb_backed` and include that in 
`hiredis.c`.

Or, forward declare it and take a pointer:

```
typedef struct git_odb_backend git_odb_backend;

typedef struct {
    git_odb_backend*parent;
    redisContext *db;
} hiredis_backend;
```